# Liquid cooling tubes resting on GPU chip. Is this okay?

Tags: gpu

I have like no room in in my computer case and the way stuff is positioned my rubber liquid cooling tubes touch my GPU chip. Will this affect anything?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't ideal due to vibrations and cooling. You can use zip-ties to pull the tube away from things that could in the long term damage the cooling pipe/GPU.

Buy the smallest zip-tie size, join them together if necessary, and don't pull them up too tightly or they can be difficult to remove in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> my rubber liquid cooling tubes touch my GPU chip. Will this affect anything?

If it is a very old system with a GPU which produces almost no heat and the cooling tubes are not hot then it should not be a problem. But for any semi-modern setup I would expect at least a heatsink on the GPU chip and adding heat to that is not a good thing.

Which bring us to: Just how much hot are those rubber tubes? If they do not block heat radiating or convecting away from the chip and they are not all that hot themselves (e.g. <50C then it probably is not a problem.